# Why does python3 not create a folder from a list if the list items begins with a '.'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python script, that will help me clean up a directory.

What the script does is: It takes a given directory, that has lots of different files with lots of different file extensions. The script then creates subdirectories with the file-extension as the name of the subdirectory and puts all files with a certain extension into its corresponding directory.

However, I ran into a problem with a portion of my code:

```
import os
def file_creator(Dir_path):
    list_file_ext = ['.png', '.pdf', '', '.docx', '.htm', '.xlsx', '.jpg']
    for file_entension in list_file_ext:
        if not os.path.exists(Dir_path + '/' + file_entension):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(Dir_path,file_entension))
```

The problem is when the file extensions begin with a '.', no files are created and no error message is displayed. However when I remove the '.' at the beginning of the file extensions it works fine and the files are created. Why is this?

At this point you might say, why dont you write:

```
#The line below uses list comprehensions to replace '' with 'No_file_ext' in list_file_ext
    list_file_ext = ['No_file_ext' if x == '' else x for x in list_file_ext]
# The line below uses list comprehensions to remove the . from the beggining of file extensions
    list_file_ext = [item[1:] if item[0] == '.' else item for item in list_file_ext]
```

However, I dont want to do this because:

The final portion of my code is:

```
    for file in os.listdir(Dir_path):
        file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        os.rename(Dir_path + '/' + file, Dir_path + '/' + file_ext + '/' + file)
```

If i format my file extensions before this, the portion above becomes much messier.

Here is source code of my script to give some context to my problem:

```
def file_types(Dir_path):
    '''the line below calculates the number of files in a directory,
    the part after if, checks if the item is a file, to ensure subdirectories are
    not included'''
    num_file_in_dir = len([file for file in os.listdir(Dir_path) if os.path.isfile(file)])

    # The block of code below, creates a list of the unique file extensions of files in a directory
    list_file_ext = []
    n= 1
    while n < num_file_in_dir:
        for file in os.listdir(Dir_path):
            file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            if file_ext not in list_file_ext:
                list_file_ext.append(file_ext)
            n = n+1

    #The line below uses list comprehensions to replace '' with 'No_file_ext' in list_file_ext
    list_file_ext = ['No_file_ext' if x == '' else x for x in list_file_ext]
    # The line below uses list comprehensions to remove the . from the beggining of file extensions
    list_file_ext = [item[1:] if item[0] == '.' else item for item in list_file_ext]
    print(list_file_ext)
    #The line below creates sub subdirectories inside the current directory corresponding to items in list_file_ext
    for file_entension in list_file_ext:
        if not os.path.exists(Dir_path + '/' + file_entension):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(Dir_path,file_entension))


    #The final stage is to move files into their folders depending on their extension.
    for file in os.listdir(Dir_path):
        file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        os.rename(Dir_path + '/' + file, Dir_path + '/' + file_ext + '/' + file)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this or ways to change the final portion of my code, if i decided to use list comprehensions earlier on?
Thanks, i hope if all makes sense.

Comment: "_no files are created_" - how do you know? The files whose names start with a period are hidden and not shown by `ls`, unless you run `ls -a`.

Comment: did you check if the directories are just hidden? linux hides stuff that starts with . by convention

Answer (score 1):

On some operating systems files which names begin with a dot are hidden from the user. If you have linux/unix based system then this is just such a case. To list hidden files run command bellow in terminal:

```
ls -a
```